# Xamarin Essentials WebAuthenticator NULL on login with IdentityServer... WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity.OnCreate NullReferenceException

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin.android, identityserver4, xamarin.essentials

I have the following setup:

Xamarin Forms App: V4.8.0

Xamarin Essentials: 1.60 - WebAuthenticator

IdentityServer4

Client: Android v10

I am using IdentityServer for authentication. On the odd occasion when a user attempts to log in, they get the following error message:

> WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity.OnCreate NullReferenceException

Once this happens, I have no fix.  This means the user is unable to login with their device, therefore unable use the app... This is causing bad reviews, so I'd like to resolve this or at the very least provide an explanation as to what is going on.

This only seems to be an issue on Android. I have found few examples of others having issues with Android v11, but theirs looks like a new bug introduced in a new version that I am not using. Also I am using v10 Android.

The strange thing here is that it seems each device affected by this error is a Xiaomi or unbranded Chinese tablet or phone.  Could someone explain in what circumstances I would get this error message?  Could it be that these devices are compromised and WebAuthenticator is picking up on this somehow? Or could it be some OS security that these devices have switched off?

Any help to understand what is happening here is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to update Xamarin Essentials to the new version ?

Comment: I have upgraded to 1.61 which is due out in our next release. I can't verify if this will solve the problem because I cannot personally replicate it... so its simply a waiting game to see if or when this happens again.  I was hoping someone would have had a similar issue or know more than I do about WebAuthenticator / IdentityServer and be able to advise what's going on. I am aware that upgrading to v1.61 does not solve this for Android v11.

Comment: If your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API 30) you must update your Android Manifest with queries that are used with the new package visibility requirements.And add a intent  inside of the manifest node.Refer to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/pull/3206#issuecomment-756888610.

Comment: My target version on the app is set to 10 at the moment... and the device this is a problem with is also v10. Maybe moving the target to 11 and adding the manifest change would solve it? I'll happily do this, but don't want to be going down the trial and error route with the project if possible. I'd like to see if anyone has information on this before I start making random changes to my project... I can't even verify the changes I make have worked, so this is a tough one to crack.

Comment: You could report it to the [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues).I think a new version will come out later to fix it.